# Labeling Region in a Plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Do you have any idea how in the resulted plot the name of each region, "region 1", "refion 2" etc, can be shown on the plot clearly?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

y = np.arange(0,15,.01)
x = np.arange(0,10,.01)

Y,X = np.meshgrid(y,x) 

maxf = np.zeros(shape = Y.shape)
maxf.fill(-9999.99) 


for i,x_ in enumerate(x):
    for j, y_ in enumerate(y):
        if y_<x_<5 or y_<5<x_:
            maxf[i,j] =3
        elif x_<5<=y_<(x_+5) or 5<=y_<x_:
            maxf[i,j] =1
        elif 5<x_<=y_<(x_+5) or x_<=y_<5:
            maxf[i,j] =2
        elif x_ == 5 and y_<5:
            maxf[i,j]=3
        elif x_ == 5 and y_>=5:
            maxf[i,j]=1
        elif y_ >= (5+x_):
            maxf[i,j]=4


plt.contourf(X,Y,maxf,[0,1,2,3,4])
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Right now the result is like the following picture:

[image]

But I need the plot to be sth like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do that by using ax.text.